# Scrolling to top when the route changes in React router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom@6.16.0` and I am facing a problem. The routing is working fine but when I am in the middle of the page and click on any link in my navbar or any other link to route to another page the next page opens from the center and not from the top. After some digging, I discovered that there is a `ScrollRestoration` component from `react-router-dom` that can be used to scroll to the top instead of the traditional `useEffect` scroll to top solution. But in the example that they have given, I didn't understand how to use it inside  `createBrowserRouter`.

Here is the code from my app.js file:

```
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import {
  Courses,
  Error,
  Home,
  HomeLayout,
  Login,
  Register,
  Testing,
  Course,
  Contact,
  About,
  FAQ,
  Events,
  EventDetails,
  Library,
  Admin,
} from '@/pages'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <HomeLayout />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: 'courses',
        element: <Courses />,
      },
      {
        path: 'single-course',
        element: <Course />,
      },
      {
        path: 'testing',
        element: <Testing />,
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        element: <Contact />,
      },
      {
        path: 'about-us',
        element: <About />,
      },
      {
        path: 'faq',
        element: <FAQ />,
      },
      {
        path: 'events',
        element: <Events />,
      },
      {
        path: 'event-details',
        element: <EventDetails />,
      },
      {
        path: 'library',
        element: <Library />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    element: <Register />,
  },
  {
    path: '/admin',
    element: <Admin />,
  },
])

const App = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ScrollRestoration` component also only works with the data routers, so you ***have*** to use one of the routers created using `createBrowserRouter`, `createMemoryRouter`, etc.

From the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/scroll-restoration):

> > **IMPORTANT**
> >
> > This feature only works if using a data router, see [Picking a
> > Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)
>
> You should only render one of these and it's recommended you render it
> in the root route of your app

Create a layout route component to render as the root route element that renders `ScrollRestoration` ***and*** an `Outlet` for the nested routes.

Example:

```
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
...

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <ScrollRestoration />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <HomeLayout />,
        errorElement: <Error />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Home /> },
          { path: 'courses', element: <Courses /> },
          { path: 'single-course', element: <Course /> },
          { path: 'testing', element: <Testing /> },
          { path: 'contact', element: <Contact /> },
          { path: 'about-us', element: <About /> },
          { path: 'faq', element: <FAQ /> },
          { path: 'events', element: <Events /> },
          { path: 'event-details', element: <EventDetails /> },
          { path: 'library', element: <Library /> },
        ],
      },
      { path: '/login', element: <Login /> },
      { path: '/register', element: <Register /> },
      { path: '/admin', element: <Admin /> },
    ]
  },
]);

const App = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code properly works:

```
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter, ScrollRestoration } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  Courses,
  Error,
  Home,
  HomeLayout,
  Login,
  Register,
  Testing,
  Course,
  Contact,
  About,
  FAQ,
  Events,
  EventDetails,
  Library,
  Admin,
} from '@/pages';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  // Your route configuration here
]);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
      {/* Wrap your RouterProvider with ScrollRestoration */}
      <ScrollRestoration onBeforeRestore={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
        <div>
          {/* Your other components */}
        </div>
      </ScrollRestoration>
    </RouterProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

import ScrollRestocration from 'react-router-dom' and wrap your RouterProvider component with the ScrollRestoration component and seet the onBeforeRestore callback to scroll to the top of the page. In this example, window.scrollTo(0, 0) is used to scroll to the top after that when you navigate to a new route, the page will scroll to the top automaticsally.

Comment: You may want to check out the [ScrollRestorationProps](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/f9b3dbd9cbf513366c456b33d95227f42f36da63/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L869-L872) and [RouterProviderProps](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/f9b3dbd9cbf513366c456b33d95227f42f36da63/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L56-L60) interfaces and reconsider your answer.